# generating client libraries for Spring data rest service

Tags: client, spring-data-rest

I am writing spring data rest service and would like to generate Java client as a jar file for use by my other project. So is there some automated way to generate client or do I have to write one myself.  If either way can you help me get started with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Spring Data Web Exporter Client but that seems to be good way to go but if you want to go the other way and write your own client you can use Spring RestTemplate to consume all the url on your server side.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Spring Data Web Exporter Client](https://github.com/onlyabout/spring-data-rest-client). You can assembly build script to create client jar archive.